# How to stop printing for "ps" function in "twang" package?

Tags: r

The "ps" function (propensity score estimation) in "twang" package in R keeps printing its report. How can I turn that off?

I already tried to set the "print.level" argument to be 0. But it is not working for me.

```
D = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
X1 = rnorm(100)
X2 = rnorm(100)
ps(D ~ ., data = data.frame(D, X1, X2), stop.method = 'es.mean',  
estimand = "ATE", print.level = 0)
```

I hope there is no printing of the process, but it keeps giving me something like:

Fitting gbm model
Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1        1.3040             nan     0.0100       nan
     2        1.3012             nan     0.0100       nan
     3        1.2985             nan     0.0100       nan
     4        1.2959             nan     0.0100       nan
     5        1.2932             nan     0.0100       nan
     6        1.2907             nan     0.0100       nan
     7        1.2880             nan     0.0100       nan
     8        1.2855             nan     0.0100       nan
     9        1.2830             nan     0.0100       nan
    10        1.2804             nan     0.0100       nan
    20        1.2562             nan     0.0100       nan
.....

which is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to capture the result in a variable; if you combine that with the `verbose = FALSE` parameter, it should do what you need:

```
res <- ps(D ~ ., data = data.frame(D, X1, X2), stop.method = 'es.mean', 
   estimand = "ATE", print.level = 0, verbose = FALSE)
```

I haven't tested whether you still need `print.level = 0`.